# Queue failed at first time and passed in second time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

My Queue job is working well. I started my queue and push my first job to it. I can see two processing in my command prompt and only one processed message in it and the operation in the job is working twice without error, but it shows only one processed message in command prompt

started a queue by Queue:work command
push a job to it
it shows two processing message in command prompt
and only one processed message

Comment: public function handle()
    {
        
        if($this->type == 'product'){
            $this->product_import();
        }else if($this->type == 'category'){
            $this->category_import();
        }else if($this->type == 'attribute'){
            $this->attribute_import();
        }
        else if($this->type == 'asset'){
           return  $this->asset_import();
        }
    }
function assert_import(){
//some code
echo "end of import";
return $result;

}

Comment: $ php artisan queue:work
[2019-08-05 17:07:42][76] Processing: App\Jobs\ProductImport
[2019-08-05 17:07:43][77] Processing: App\Jobs\ProductImport
ENDS[2019-08-05 17:07:43][77] Processed:  App\Jobs\ProductImport

Comment: I would put your code snippet and output into your question rather than in the comments if possible.

Comment: @GunaSmart Please add the code in the question not as a comment. You can use the `edit` button to update your question.

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui Thank you dude Am a noobie programmer :)